# In finite or countably infinite sample spaces, why are events with probability zero impossible?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space. If $\Omega$ is uncountable, and $E\in\mathcal F$, then it could be that $\mathbb P(E)=0$ even though $E$ is a possible event. However, as far as I know, this cannot occur if $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite. Is there a proof of this?

The main stumbling block to proving this statement is that I have not found a precise definition of "impossible event". I have heard the empty set being described as "the impossible event", but that does not seem to shed much light here. For instance, consider the following set-up:

- $\Omega=\{0,1\}$
- $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(\Omega)$
- $\mathbb P(\varnothing)=0$, $\mathbb P(\{0\})=1,\mathbb P(\{1\})=0,\mathbb P(\Omega)=1$.

In this case, $\mathbb P(\{1\})=0$, but it is not the case that $\{1\}=\varnothing$. Hence, if $\{1\}$ is to be regarded as an "impossible event", then it seems we cannot simply define an impossible event as the empty set.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for non-empty sets to have measure zero, regardless of cardinality (heck even with the usual Lebesgue measure on the real line, the middle-thirds Cantor set is uncountable with measure zero). This depends only on the definition of the measure. So yes, what needs to be changed is our interpretation of the word "impossible".

Comment: Is it reasonable to say that 1 is in your sample space? Why not take the sample space to be all of the natural numbers and take $\mathbb P(\{n\})=0$ for $n>0$?

Comment: @Paul: I did consider this, but if $1$ is not in the sample space, then $\mathbb P(\{1\})$ is undefined, rather than $0$, which does not seem satisfactory.

Comment: Why not $\Omega =\{0 \}$ and $\mathbb P(\{0\})=1$. Why include 1 in the sample space at all?

Comment: @Paul: Does my above comment not answer your question?

Comment: Whoever told you that probability zero implies impossible lied

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Note that my question only considers countable sample spaces. Are you saying that even in this case, an event can have probability $0$ and be possible?

Comment: Say $\Omega=\{0,1\}$. For $E\subset\Omega$ let $P(E)$ be $1$ i $1\in E$, $0$ otherwise. Let $E=\{0\}$. Then $E\ne\emptyset$, which is the only mathemattical interpretation I can think of for "$E$ is possible", but $P(E)=0$. (Hmm, one of the answers links to a britanica article that does indeed define "possible" this way...)

Comment: You want to _mathematically prove_ something for which there is no _mathematical definition_ (what does it even mean for something to be impossible?). How is this question not closed?

Comment: @WilliamM.: But the purpose of my question *is* to find a satisfactory mathematical definition of impossibility. I have seen the term "impossible event" being used as a synonym for the "empty set", but while that definition is no doubt precise, it does not seem to capture our everyday notion of what we mean when we say an event is impossible. Essentially, I'm asking if there is more satisfying mathematical characterisation of impossibility.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage of "impossible event"? I have never heard that used, I always hear the expression "event of probability zero" or "null event" (most common choice). In fact, I don't think the term impossible event is defineable. I don't consider the empty set an impossible event, because certainly nothing happening is an event! (And is therefore possible.)

Comment: It seems to me  that you are confusing probability theory (an abstract mathematical theory that tries to capture what we intuitively understand as "randomness") with something else, something like "what are the possible outcomes in a given experiment?" When a discrete probability space models an experiment with finitely many points, then yes, we usually give zero probability to the results of the experiment that are regarded _a priori_ as impossible.

Comment: @Joe: One link to Britannica in my answer explicitly mentions "impossible event".

Comment: @Joe, I see that you have accepted an answer, but I am just asking this out of curiosity. Was it the motivation behind your question that you see realizations of continuous distributions which are of probability 0, but don't see any such thing for discrete distributions? For example, any realization of a Gaussian distribution always has probability 0, but the realizations of the discrete distributions always have positive probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no proof because the statement is not even rigorous. Whether something "can occur" is not a mathematically precise thing (in this context).

However, let's let loose and play around a bit. I would definitely say that probability $0$ stuff can definitely occur in uncountable settings, and I think it can also occur in countable settings depending on the randomness generator.

For example, if we randomly choose a number uniformly from $[0,1]$ (this can be made rigorous), then $\{0\}$ has probability $0$, but if we were to say that $0$ cannot occur, then we'd have to say $x$ cannot occur, for all $x \in [0,1]$, which means that no number can occur, which is absurd. Therefore, $0$ can occur.

Now let's say our probability distribution is the example you gave: with probability $0$ we choose $0$ and with probability $1$ we choose $1$. One can generate such a probability distribution in the following two ways. First, one can choose a number uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ and then output $1$. Second, one can choose a number $x$ uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ and output $1$ if and only if $x \not = 0$. I would say that in the first case, $0$ cannot occur, while in the second case, $0$ can occur.

But, as mentioned, at the end of the day this is all nonsense. In the real world, everything is most likely discretized, so I don't feel like a crime is being committed by mathematicians not having made rigorous the notion of whether probability $0$ events can occur.

Answer (score 1):

Before "proving" anything, one needs precise definitions for all the terms used in one's statement. There is no precise definition in your post of a "possible event".

You are likely confusing yourself without having a precise meaning of "impossible event" in your mind. On the one hand, you said

> I have not found a precise definition of "impossible event"

On the other hand, you wrote

> Hence, if {1} is to be regarded as an "impossible event", then it seems we cannot simply define an impossible event as the empty set.

where you *a priori* consider in your mind an "impossible event" as an event with possibility zero: of course, you can simply define an "impossible event" as the empty set; in that case $\{1\}$ is simply **not** an "impossible event" and it has probability zero. There is no contradiction at all.

Actually, "impossible event" *is* defined as the empty set. See for instance [this encyclopedia article](https://www.britannica.com/science/probability-theory/The-principle-of-additivity):

> The impossible event—i.e., the event containing no outcomes—is denoted by Ø.

You can find more references if you search `"impossible events"+"impossible event"` in https://books.google.com/.

[Notes: the empty set is also called the "surely false event" or "empty event", while an event that has probability zero is called "almost surely false event" or "null event". See e.g. [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/275a-notes-0-foundations-of-probability-theory/) set of lecture notes.]

Now, under such definition, any event, i.e., any nonempty set that is an element in the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, is called a "possible event". It is totally possible that $P(E)=0$ even if the event $E$ is not empty. This is independent of the cardinality of the probability space.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, there isn't really a precise definition of "impossible event."  I think the best way to interpret what you're asking about in this question is to note that, if the sample space $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite and contains events with probability $0$, we could instead consider our sample space to be just the events that have positive probability, i.e. remove the "impossible" events.  In other words, while we could have a countable sample space that has events with probability $0$, we can always just consider the sample space to be those events with non-zero probability instead.

More precisely, if $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $\Omega$ is countable, then there exists a probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal F', \mathbb{P}')$ with $\Omega' \subset \Omega$, $\mathcal F' \subset \mathcal F$, $\mathbb{P}'(E) > 0$ for all $E \in \mathcal F'$ with $E \ne \emptyset$, and $\mathbb{P}'(E) = \mathbb{P}(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal F'$.

To do this, let $N := \{\omega \in \Omega : \text{there exists }E \in \mathcal F \text{ with } \omega \in E \text{ and }\mathbb{P}(E) = 0 \}$ (the idea is that $N$ is the set of $\omega$ in the sample space that have probability $0$, we just have to be careful because $\{\omega\}$ may not always be measurable).  For each $\omega \in N$, we can find $E_{\omega} \in \mathcal F$ with $\mathbb{P}(E_{\omega}) = 0$.  Since $N \subset \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is countable, $N$ is also countable.  Therefore $J := \bigcup_{\omega \in N} E_\omega$ is a countable union of measurable sets and hence measurable, and $N \subset J$.  Furthermore, we have $$\mathbb{P}(J) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{\omega \in N} E_\omega\right) \le \sum_{\omega \in N} \mathbb{P}(E_{\omega}) = 0.$$   Let $\Omega' := \Omega \setminus J$.  Since $\Omega$ and $J$ were both measurable, $\Omega'$ is also measurable and therefore $\mathcal F' := \mathcal F \vert_{\Omega'}$ is a well-defined $\sigma$-algebra.  Let $\mathbb{P}' := \mathbb{P}\vert_{\mathcal F'}$.  Since $\mathbb{P}(J) = 0$, $\mathbb{P}(\Omega') = \mathbb{P}(\Omega \setminus J) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega) - \mathbb{P}(J) = 1$ so $(\Omega',\mathcal F', \mathbb{P}')$ is a probability space.  Let $E \in \mathcal F'$ be non-empty; we will show $\mathbb{P}'(E) > 0$.  Suppose working towards a contradiction that $\mathbb{P}'(E) = 0$.  Since $\mathbb{P}'$ is the restriction of $\mathbb{P}$, this implies $\mathbb{P}(E) = 0$ as well.  Thus if $\omega \in E$, we also have $\omega \in N$ by construction, which contradictions our construction of $\Omega'$.  Hence we must have $\mathbb{P}'(E) > 0$ for all non-empty $E \in \mathcal F'$ as desired.

This breaks down if $\Omega$ is uncountable because then $N$ may be uncountable as well, so there is no reason that $J$ would need to be a null-set.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the countable case impossible events are just not listed because are irrelevant, so zero probability sets are totally possible, but aren't usefull, as example, thinking in the experiment of throwing a coin one time, the sample space is Heads or Tails $\Omega =\{H,\,T\}$, and defined in this standard way, by probability axioms it leads that each of them have probability of $1/2$... but here an assumption was been made (a sensefull one), and it is that you have given $0$ probability to ever other possible outcomes (like the coin dissapearing mid-air, or it jumps to space an never come back, or a more reallistic one, that is the coin landing on its edge, which I have already seen it happen a few times in my 36 years here on earth XD)....

In the uncountable case, like in continuous random variables, you can't ommit them as easily, and you always have, at least in continuous random variables, that there always a $0$ probability of "landing" in an unique value since the CDF integral will have the same number in the lower and upper integration limits $P_{cont.}(x=X)=\int\limits_{X}^{X} f_x(u) du=0$, so the zero probability cases are more evidently stated.... but I don't see why, if you want, you could list the coin toss sample space as $\Omega =\{H,\,T,\,Edge\}$ with $P(H)=P(T)=1/2$ and $P(Edge)=0$, but is not really usefull as much as stating explicitly you are letting some outcomes out of the experiment results.